# обращение к соседним элементам в списке python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Изучаю Python по курсам на Cтепике и уже неделю бьюсь над задачей из курса, где:

> На вход подаётся список чисел одной строкой.
>   Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести сумму двух его соседей.
>
> Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними, одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце этого списка.
>   Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же.
>   Вывод должен содержать одну строку с числами нового списка, разделёнными пробелом.

В ходе долгих размышлений, перелопачивания интернета и тд. Родил такой код:

```py
    numbers = [i for i in input().split()] # создание списка из введенных чисел
    if len(numbers) == 1:     # условие при котором выводит одиночное число назад 
        print (numbers[0])
    else:
        b = numbers             # создаем список, где последнее число добавляем в
        b.append (numbers[0])       # начало, а первое в конец для удовлетворения 
        b.insert(0,numbers[-2])     # условий по крайним элементам
        result = []                 # список с 'конечным' результатом
        for i in b[1:-1]:           # перебор элементов от индекса 1, до -2
            y = i[i-1] + i[i+1]     # сосед слева от i + сосед справа от i
            result.append(y)        # добавление результата сложения в ответ
        print (result)
```

Но все попытки обратиться по индексам к 'соседям' `i` приводят к ошибкам...
Помогите неопытному разобраться что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в коде ошибка в строке:

```
y = i[i-1] + i[i+1]     # сосед слева от i + сосед справа от i
```

`i` это элемент списка, т.е. число. Поэтому вы пытаетесь из числа вытянуть какой-то элемент, из за чего и выдаётся исключение. Для решения проблемы, можно воспользоваться методом [enumerate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/) или же пройтись по значениям индексов с помощью [range](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).

После чего код цикла будет такой:

```
for i in range(1,len(b)-1):           # перебор элементов от индекса 1, до -2
    y = b[i-1] + b[i+1]     # сосед слева от i + сосед справа от i
    result.append(y)
```

UPD: Ещё одна ошибка в первой строке.

```
numbers = [i for i in input().split()]
```

Вы записываете в список числа в строковом виде (`['1','2','3']`), для того чтобы переделать строки в числа нужно воспользоваться методом [int](https://www.w3resource.com/python/built-in-function/int.php):

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

Comment: Вы золотой человек. Я пытался задавать range, но он так же выдавал мне ошибку, потому что я задавал len(b-1), а не len(b)-1... а с вашей помощью, все получилось! Спасибо Вам огромное.